# Error fetching a record and associating it with .build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an error putting `.build` into a specific record that I look for this way:

```
@ruta = Ruta.find_by_IdRutas(166)
```

Showing me the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'RutaID', table
>   'database.dbo.Continuidad'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
>   fails.: EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE [continuidad] SET [RutaID] = @0
>   WHERE [continuidad].[RutaID] = @1; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows',
>   N'@0 int, @1 int', @0 = NULL, @1 = 166):
>    app/controllers/rutas_controller.rb:54:in `datos_ruta'

The error only occurs with records that have records related to the `continuid` table, but when it does not have related records it does not display the error.

This is my `index` action:

```
def index
  @ruta = Ruta.find_by_IdRutas(166)
  @ruta.build_continuid
end
```

This is my `form` in index view:

```
<%= form_for(@ruta, :method => :put, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal formulario-validado-update"}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->
  <div nohidden class="modal fade si" id="myupdateruta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Ruta</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :Ruta, "Número de Ruta:", class: "control-label col-md-3" %>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <%= f.text_field :Ruta, class: "form-control", required: "true" %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <%= f.fields_for :continuid do |continuid| %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= continuid.label :FolDevol, "Folio de devolución:", class: "control-label col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5" %>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                  <%= continuid.text_field :FolDevol, class: "form-control " %>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <%= submit_tag "Actualizar", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { disable_with: 'Actualizando' }%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `Ruta` model:

```
has_one :continuid, class_name: "Continuid", foreign_key: "RutaID"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :continuid
```

This is my `Continuid` model:

```
belongs_to :ruta, class_name:"Ruta", foreign_key: "RutaID"
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the complete log output?

Comment: You shouldnt capitalize your foreign key variable.  It should be snakecase and be ruta_id

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thanks for replying, I understand but because I am working with a database previously created the foreign key has that name

Comment: If you have the Ruta ID (in your example its 166) you should do: Ruta.find(166).continuid  #This will get your continuid record

Comment: @bkunzi01 Only to get the record with "Ruta.find(166)" and place it "<%= f.fields_for :continuid do |continuid| %>" I already get its related record but the problem comes when the record "Ruta" does not have a related record "continuid" then it does not display the form fields, unlike the create form that has a ruta = Ruta.new  with ruta.build_contiuind